# extracting parts of a file to different file with sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

I want to write a script to extract parts of my data file and save it in different files. I wrote a script but it gives some error. The script is

```bash
#!/bin/bash

nn=0
mn=0

for var1 in 1 2 3 ; do
    nn=nn+2
    mn=mn+302

    sed -n '$nn','$mn'p  dos.dat > $var1.dat

    nn=mn
done
```

Comment: what error....?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem with your script is that the variables are single-quoted, preventing them from being expanded by the shell:

```
sed -n '$nn','$mn'p dos.dat > $var1.dat
```

Perhaps you meant something like

```
sed -n "$nn,${mn}p" dos.dat > $var1.dat
```

where the second variable is delimited with `{` and `}` to separate it from `p`.

Also, the expression syntax is a problem.  The variables on the right hand side of "=" need "$" to get their value.  Without treating them with '$((' or `expr`, the right hand side also is just a string — not a number.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nn=0 ; mn=0
for var1 in 1 2 3 ; do
    nn=$(($nn+2))
    mn=$(($mn+302))

    sed -n "$nn,${mn}p" dos.dat > $var1.dat

    nn=$mn
done
```

According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), the '$' within `$((` is unnecessary: either would work:

> If the shell variable ***`x`*** contains a value that forms a valid integer constant, optionally including a leading plus or minus sign, then the arithmetic expansions ***`"$((x))"`*** and ***`"$(($x))"`*** shall return the same value.

Comment: You don't have to `$` vairables in arithmetic expansion.

Comment: It works, and I started thinking of `expr` first before settling on bash-specifics.

Comment: Note that `nn=nn+2` will work in ksh/zsh/bash if the variable was previously declared as integer (`typeset -i nn`).

Comment: But I don't see `typeset` in POSIX, and as a rule I start off by checking if there was a valid need for non-POSIX features before considering how to improve their use.  In this case, there was no such need.